Linearization coefficients for Jacobi polynomials
In general, for families of polynomials $\{ Q_n\}, \{ R_n\},\{S_n\}$, there exist linearization coefficients such that one may write the product $Q_m R_n = \sum_k c_{m,n}^k S_k$.
Let $P^{\alpha,\beta}_n(x)$ denote the Jacobi polynomial on $(-1,1)$ which are orthogonal with respect to the weight $(1-x)^\alpha(1+x)^\beta$, and $P^{\alpha,\beta}_n(1) = {n+\alpha \choose n} $.
I am particularly interested in the case $Q_n =P^{0,1}_n$,
$R_n = P^{1,0}_n$ and $S_n = P^{1,1}_n$. That is, the linearization coefficients
$$P^{0,1}_m(x) P^{1,0}_n (x) = \sum_k c_{m,n}^k P^{1,1}_k(x)$$
The coefficients $c_{m,n}^k$ need not be positive. However based on numerical experiments, it seems that there is a constant $ \kappa\geq 1$  such that
$$
 \sum_k |c_{m,n}^k | \leq \kappa
$$
for all $m,n$. I think $\kappa \approx 5/4$, I am at a bit of a loss on trying to prove this for any $\kappa$. The best reference I could find (in terms of relevance and my ability to understand it) is the following:
Koornwinder, Tom. "Positivity proofs for linearization and connection coefficients of orthogonal polynomials satisfying an addition formula." Journal of the London Mathematical Society 2.1 (1978): 101-114.
However my desired result does not seems to directly follow from this work.

You can compute the coefficients $c_{m,n}^k$ explicitly as follows. First use that
$$P_n^{(0,1)}=\frac{n+2}{2n+2},P_n^{(1,1)}+\frac 12,P_{n-1}^{(1,1)},$$
$$P_n^{(1,0)}=\frac{n+2}{2n+2},P_n^{(1,1)}-\frac 12,P_{n-1}^{(1,1)}.$$
Then use that
$$P_m^{(1,1)}P_n^{(1,1)}=\sum_{k=0}^{\min(m,n)}d_{m,n}^k P_{m+n-2k}^{(1,1)},$$
where $d_{m,n}^k$ are known explicitly, see e.g. R. Askey, Orthogonal polynomials and special functions, 1975, eq. (5.7).

To elaborate on my previous comment, I get
$$c_{m,n}^{m+n-2k}=\frac{m+n+2}{2(m+1)(n+1)}\frac{m+n-2k+3/2}{m+n-2k+1}\frac{(2){m+n-k}}{(3/2){m+n-k+1}}\frac{(3/2){m-k}(3/2){n-k}}{(m-k)!(n-k)!}\frac{(1/2)k}{k!},$$
$$c{m,n}^{m+n-2k-1}=\frac{n-m}{(m+1)(n+1)}\frac{m+n-2k+1/2}{m+n-2k}\frac{(2){m+n-k}}{(3/2){m+n-k}}\frac{(1/2){m-k}(1/2){n-k}}{(m-k)!(n-k)!}\frac{(3/2)_k}{k!}.$$
But I wonder why you want to estimate the quantity $\sum_k|c_{m,n}^k|$. This seems to depend on the precise normalization of Jacobi polynomials, which to my understanding is just a historical coincidence.

Thank you Hjalmar Rosengren for these references! The motivation comes from a PDE problem where solutions are represented in terms of Disk/Zernike polynomials. Different normalizations of the Jacobi polynomials correspond to imposing different weighted norms on the space of functions. For an appropriate normalization, these spaces form a Banach algebra, see:
<<<
KANJIN, YÛICHI. "Banach algebra related to disk polynomials." Tohoku Mathematical Journal, Second Series 37.3 (1985): 395-404.





However the normalizations I'm interested appear to be stronger than these prior results.
